# pg_dump of a 4 GB+ PostgreSQL Database directly on a mounted S3 bucket gives error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, pg-dump

I have mounted S3 bucket in CentOS 6.8 on the partition '/var/db/s3' other than the one reserved for PostgreSQL database.  Then, I took a dump of the database, as root user, in mountpoint 'mon' (S3 bucket) using the following command:

```
# pg_dump --blob -Fc testdb -f /var/db/s3/mon/testdb_bk
```

It fails with the following error:

```
pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not close archive file: Input/output error
```

Then, I tried the same on a local partition, /var, and it worked.  The size of the database dump was about 4.5 GB.

I then tried to write another database, that was much smaller in size, about 65 MB using the same procedure on the mounted S3 bucket and it worked fine!

I can't figure out why 4.5 GB database is giving error while writing directly on a mounted S3 bucket and a smaller database dump goes fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: The man page of s3fs states: s3fs currently has a natural limit of 5GB per file. If that happens to be 5,000,000,000 bytes (shouldn't, IIRC, but one never knows), that is just over 4.5 * 2^30

Comment: I can directly make a tar of 11 GB on a mounted S3 bucket, but pg_dump of about 4.5 GB gives Input/output error.  Is it something to do with pg_dump then?

Comment: As a kind of test you could try to store the backup on another device. If that works, the problem lies in the S3 bucket, else there's an issue with pg_dump. A smaller backup, e.g. one that has a size between 3 and 4GB would give a nice experiment too.

Comment: I have tested with a smaller database of about 100 MB with pg_dump and it works fine.

Comment: So you wrote. But 100MB is far less than 2GB (max number in a signed int) or 4GB (max number in an unsigned int). Both Postgres (at least theoretically) and the S3 bucket can have an issue with those numbers. This is why I suggested to do a `pg_dump` to another location (rule out pg as a cause) and other tests to check the behaviour between 4GB and 5GB (due to the limitation mentioned by the man page I've found), as well as 2GB and 4GB to test the behaviour beyond 2GB.

Comment: pg_dump of 4.5GB works on a local partition, but not on mounted S3 bucket.

Comment: That's what I've expected. Hence the S3 bucket doesn't act like a file system near a file size between 4.5 and 5GB. You could backup to a local partition and then split the file and write the chunks to your S3 partition. In case of a restore you concatenate the chunks and then do the action. Does that sound like an option?

Comment: I have already checked that pg_dump on local disk goes fine and also the sync towards S3 bucket.  But, I wonder, if tar can write 11GB directly on a mounted S3 bucket, why pg_dump can't write 4.5GB dump?  What is different in tar and pg_dump process and what exactly creates the issue, is it s3fs or pg_dump or something else?